# onClick not behaving as expected when used in a material-ui List with Buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use React / Material-UI to create a custom list, where each item has a `Checkbox`, a text label and a button. The onClick for the `Checkbox` should be handled by a different function to the onClick for the `Button`.

I am getting two unexpected behaviours:

1. When the page loads, the onClick for the `Button` runs for each item in the list.
2. Clicking a `Button` doesn't trigger the handler function.

I suspect this has something to do with event bubbling, but I'm fairly new to JS as well as React/Material-UI and I can't seem to figure it out.

Minimal example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/listhelp-l199j?file=/src/App.js but the key part of the code is as follows

```
<ListItem key={value.name} role="listitem">
  <ListItemIcon>
    <Checkbox
      checked={checked.indexOf(value) !== -1}
      tabIndex={-1}
      disableRipple
      inputProps={{ "aria-labelledby": labelId }}
      onClick={handleToggleChecked(value)}
      edge="start"
    />
  </ListItemIcon>
  <ListItemText id={labelId} primary={value.name} />
  <ListItemIcon>
    <Button onClick={handleOpenSettings(value)}>
      Edit<EditIcon />
    </Button>
  </ListItemIcon>
</ListItem>
```

I've seen the Material-UI have a very similar example, here: https://codesandbox.io/s/8091z?file=/demo.js  which works if I add code trigger different functions for the `Checkbox` and `IconButton`. I don't see what the difference is between my code and theirs, which would cause the different behaviours.

Comment: In your codesandbox example you're not passing the event handler to the `onClick` for the `Button`, but instead calling the function.

Comment: As @EmilDimitrov stated, you should pass a callback not call the function ```() => handleOpenSettings(value)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ListItem key={value.name} role="listitem">
  <ListItemIcon>
    <Checkbox
      checked={checked.indexOf(value) !== -1}
      tabIndex={-1}
      disableRipple
      inputProps={{ "aria-labelledby": labelId }}
      onClick={() => handleToggleChecked(value)}
      edge="start"
    />
  </ListItemIcon>
  <ListItemText id={labelId} primary={value.name} />
  <ListItemIcon>
    <Button onClick={() => handleOpenSettings(value)}>
      Edit<EditIcon />
    </Button>
  </ListItemIcon>
</ListItem>
```

Comment: This works for the button, but now the `Checkbox` doesn't respond. I can only get it to work when I use `onClick={handleToggleChecked(value)}` for the `Checkbox` and `onClick={() => handleOpenSettings(value)}` for the `Button`. Any idea why they need different syntax?